# Problem executing a batch file in a Java application

Tags: java, batch-file

I have batch file, named run.bat which inlcudes the following code:

```
@echo off
REM bat windows script
set CXF_HOME=.\lib\apache-cxf-2.2.7
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CXF_HOME%\logging.properties -jar archiveServer-0.1.jar
```

When I execute this file on a command line it works perfectly. However when I try to execute within a java file with the following statement:

```
File path = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/Zatko/My Documents/Project-workspace/IUG/external/application/archive");    

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "run.bat"}, new String[]{}, path);
```

I get the following error in the terminal window:

```
'java' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Where the error may be?

Answer (score 2):

Java.exe is not found in your PATH.

If you can assume that the JAVA_HOME variable is defined, you can modify your batch file:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CXF_HOME%\logging.properties -jar archiveServer-0.1.jar
```

A better way to do it would be, as staker suggested, to set the PATH environment variable to contain %JDK_HOME%\bin

```
File workingDirectory = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/Zatko/My Documents/Project-workspace/IUG/external/application/archive");    
String javaProgram = System.getProperty("java.home") + "\bin";
String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "run.bat"};
String[] environment = {"PATH=" + javaProgram};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, environment, workingDirectory);
```

As a third option, you can also avoid to have the batch file by invoking the main-class of the jar directly.  You archiveServer would run in the same process, however.  Maybe that's not want you want.

Comment: +1 I fixed some minor typos, please rollback if you don't agree.

Comment: @stacker Thanks. I've just added back the workingDirectory as specified in the code of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you didn't add `JAVA_HOME/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: The value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin; is included in the PATH variable

Comment: Try to add C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin before java in your batch file. A cleaner way could be to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec() with two parameters to specified environment.

Comment: "A cleaner way could be to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec() with two parameters to specified environment", can you give me an example please?

Comment: Gawi already posted an example, see javadoc of Runtime.exec for alternatives which include the environment. I'm sorry but can't post code from my iPad.